# How to define my own notch interval in geom_boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to overwrite the default median notch interval used when calling `geom_boxplot(notch=T)`? Since my model doesn't conform to the Central Limit requirements particularly the independence and i.i.d assumptions I'd like to plug-in the requirements-free bootstrap CIs (BCa). Therefore I pre-compute the BCa on the median (my set is skewed too) and use this instead of the 95% CI generated while using `geom_boxplot(notch=T)`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a workaround is to use `stat_summary` with `geom="boxplot"`. The only thing is that you need to redefine the BCa inside the function:

```
newbox = function(values){

#usual quantile values
df = data.frame(t(boxplot(values,plot=FALSE)$stats))
colnames(df) = c("ymin","lower","middle","upper","ymax")
# bootstrap and get lower+upper notch
BOOT=boot(values,statistic=function(x,inds)median(x[inds]),R=1000)
CI=boot.ci(BOOT,type="bca")
df$notchlower = CI$bca[4]
df$notchupper = CI$bca[5]
df
}
```

Also a function to define outlier:

```
newOutlier = function(values){
 boxplot(values,plot=FALSE)$out
}
```

Now we simulate some data and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(boot)

set.seed(111)
da = data.frame(x=rep(letters[1:2],each=300),
y=rgamma(600,shape=2,scale=10))


g1 = ggplot(da, aes(x, y)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = newbox, geom = "boxplot",notch=TRUE) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = newOutlier, geom = "point")

g2 = ggplot(da, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch=TRUE) 

grid.arrange(g1,g2,ncol=2)
```

[image]